# how to pass output parameter for type date

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

I need to have output parameter which data type is date on vb.net. I know how to do it for integer. Would someone tell me how to do it for date. I am not sure the size.

```
 paramOut = New SqlParameter("@OrderID", SqlDbType.Int, 4, ParameterDirection.InputOutput, True, 10, 0, "@OrderID", DataRowVersion.Current, DBNull.Value)
```

Comment: There are many "date" types in Sql Server, which one are you talking about?  `Date`, `DateTime`, `SmallDateTime`, etc?

Comment: Do you need that long overload? The overloads that omit size will infer it automatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to specify size at all. Do this

VB.NET

```
Dim outputParm As New SqlParameter With {
    .Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,
    .ParameterName = "@OrderID",
    .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Date}
command.Parameters.Add(outputParm)
```

---

C#

```
SqlParameter outputParm = new SqlParameter
{
    Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output,
    ParameterName = "@OrderID",
    SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Date
};
command.Parameters.Add(outputParm);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `SqlDbType.DateTime`  [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)'s a good reference for those data members

Comment: This doesn't help with the size (number of bytes) of the column.  The page shows what value the column can hold, but not how big the storage requirements are